# How to code for mutually exclusive flags in Options.Applicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I'm a Haskell newbie. As a learning exercise, I'm trying to port one of my Rust programs to Haskell. In Rust, I use the amazing `clap` package, and have come across `Options.Applicative` as a good-looking alternative. Here's an example:

```
import Options.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))

data Sample = Sample
  { tod        :: Bool
  , pmc        :: Bool
  , tai        :: Bool
  }

sample :: Parser Sample
sample = Sample
      <$>  switch
          ( long "tod"
            <> short 'o'
            <> help "Convert from TOD" )
      <*> switch
          ( long "pmc"
            <> short 'p'
            <> help "Convert from PMC" ) 
      <*> switch
          ( long "tai"
            <> short 't'
            <> help "Set TAI mode" )

main :: IO ()
main = greet =<< execParser opts
  where
    opts = info (sample <**> helper) ( fullDesc )
greet :: Sample -> IO ()
greet (Sample a b c) = print [a,b,c]
```

Having got this far, I've hit a brick wall. I need to make the "tod" and "pmc" flags mutually exclusive. There's an example in the package README which uses <|>, but it's not for boolean flags, and I don't have a clue how to transform this.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Why use booleans and not an enum that can have three values?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My original "design" envisaged booleans because they fitted better into the program logic: "if utc then" rather than "if thing = Utc then".

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Pattern matching is a fundamental feature of Haskell. In fact, it is actually more fundamental (in Haskell) than `==`. You should take advantage of this. An added benefit is that this would make invalid states completely impossible to reach. It completely rules out an entire category of bugs (before the code is even run! No test-cases needed for that one). This idea of "making invalid states impossible" is an important concept in languages like Haskell.

Comment: @David Thank you. I'm very much a beginner, and I appreciate this kind of insight. -- From Daniel's solution, the elegance of this approach is dawning on me. Only a few years to go!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make one of `pmc` or `tod` be a computed value, and only store the other.

```
data Sample = Sample
    { tod :: Bool
    , tai :: Bool
    }

pmc = not . tod

sample = Sample
    <$> (   flag' True  (short 'o')
        <|> flag' False (short 'p')
        <|> pure True -- what do you want to do if they specify neither?
        )
    <*> switch (short 't')
```

Or perhaps there are actually three modes of operation. Then make both `tod` and `pmc` be computed fields.

```
data Mode = TOD | PMC | Other deriving Eq

data Sample = Sample
    { mode :: Mode
    , tai :: Bool
    }

tod = (TOD==) . mode
pmc = (PMC==) . mode

sample = Sample
    <$> (   flag' TOD (short 'o')
        <|> flag' PMC (short 'p')
        <|> pure Other
        )
    <*> switch (short 't')
```